# My google account seems to think I am living 27 hours in the past?

Tags: firefox, gmail

I recently bought a new computer and installed Windows 7, obviously when I first booted up the time was off.

I have now installed all my software. I use Firefox and Gmail hangouts all day everyday. In Hangouts the time stamps are all 27 hours in the past. In gmail messages are supposedly also 27 hours old when I first get them.

How can I set the "Google" date and time?

Comment: is the actual time correct?

Comment: The time on my desktop is correct; windows time is correct. When I view my gmail or hangouts from my phone the timestamps are correct. But the timestamps are incorrect when viewed fromy my PC

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gmail shows the times in what it thinks is your time zone, which it gets from your browser.

After setting your computer's time zone and clock, restart your browser to pick up the changes.

Comment: My timezone was off but had the correct time..